# React-router-dom: History.push concatenates path and doesn't reroute the app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, reactstrap

I have a popOver that contains a bunch of links:
[image]
This is the code implementing it:

```
   <PopoverBody>
                    <div>
                      {heart_users_profile_handles.map((heart_user) => (
                        <div>
                          <Link
                            onClick={() => {
                              this.props.history.push(
                                `profile/${heart_user.handle}`
                              );
                            }}
                          >
                            <small>{heart_user.handle}</small>
                          </Link>
                          <br />
                        </div>
                      ))}
                    </div>
                  </PopoverBody>
```

The problem is that when a user clicks on one of those links, instead of getting rerouted to them, they just get concatenated on the browser URL, and nothing happens:

The URL is originally like this:

> http://localhost:3000/profile/HamadiAgerbi

After clicking once on the first link, this happens:

> http://localhost:3000/profile/profile/AhmedGhrib

After I click on the second link this happens:

> http://localhost:3000/profile/profile/profile/BarchaHob0

And so on and so forth.

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Two things - Why are you using history.push? Can you not just use links? That would allow you to still use the mapping but would fix the problem I think. Secondly, what do your React Router routes look like (assuming that’s what you’re using)?

Answer (score 1):

change code .`profile/${heart_user.handle}` to `/profile/${heart_user.handle}`

```
<PopoverBody>
                    <div>
                      {heart_users_profile_handles.map((heart_user) => (
                        <div>
                          <Link to={`/profile/${heart_user.handle}`} >
                            <small>{heart_user.handle}</small>
                          </Link>
                          <br />
                        </div>
                      ))}
                    </div>
                  </PopoverBody>
```

Comment: It stopped concatenating it. But, still nothing happens. The app doesn't get rerouted.

Comment: change ``` <Link to={`/profile/${heart_user.handle}`}><small>{heart_user.handle}</small>     </Link>```

Comment: updated answer for test.If it still has a problem. Put your sample code in the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/).for debugging.